# Does the Facebook graph API, video_insights gives data for crossposted video?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, video, cross-posting

I have linked two pages to have crosspost access. Published a video post(Post11) in Account1 and gave permission for Account2 to crosspost the video. Account2 created a post(Post21) with the same video used in Post11. Got engagements on both the posts. Cannot see any data for Post21(i.e Crossposted video) in graph api, however can see data for Post11(i.e Original video).
Is it expected that graph API wont return anything when queried video_insights endpoint for crossposted video ?

Currently, it just returns me this

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

when the query is, 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=910714455761671%2Fvideo_insights&version=v2.8

Comment: Have you read the help pages?

Comment: Yes, have gone through, but didn't help much. I have tried the above scenario with multiple posts and accounts. Can see some insights for crossposted video in the FB Insights(in the facebook UI), but getting nothing in graph api for the same video.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it expected that graph API wont return anything when queried
>   video_insights endpoint for crossposted video ?

Yes. Graph API won't return insights for a video unless you have valid permission to read its insights. You can check the permissions required by the Graph API [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video/#permissions).

However, you need to know the difference between insights returned from `{video_id}/video_insights` and `{post_id}/insights`.

As stated in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v6.0/video/video_insights#insights-for-crossposted-videos), the first one will give you insights for the video as ***overall*** (original and crossposted posts) while the second will return data related to the post you are retrieving ***only***.

This means the data you see for *Post11* is the data from *Post11 and Post21* combined.

In your case, you can use `{post_id}/insights` to get insights of *Post11* alone and then compare the results with the one you got from `{video_id}/video_insights` to see how *Post21* performed. This, of course, if you can't get permission to *Account2* which would be so much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Graph API now returns `video_insights` results for crossposted videos:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/video-api/guides/crossposting#insights

I can't find any evidence of when this was changed.

I skimmed the changelogs and out-of-cycle logs and didn't find anything.

I've confirmed that video_insights *do* return for page owned crossposted video ids in the graph explorer.